# Problem with double quotes from PSQL JSON results

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have the following SELECT statement that is returning twice escaped double quotes and I can't figure out how to either escape them out only once or strip out the double quotes completely.  The JSON is malformed because of them. I have tried REPLACE and using various PGSQL JSON functions but nothing is giving me the results I need.  There may be a better way of writing this whole statement but I am pretty new to PostgreSQL and all the functionality it has.

```
COPY (
SELECT
    json_build_object('var pdescr = ',(array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object('ai_vsn_id', air13.ai_vsn_id, 'pde_text', progdesc.pde_text, 'pde_disp_ord', progdesc.pde_disp_ord)))))
FROM
    air13
LEFT JOIN
    progdesc
ON
    progdesc.pde_vsn_id = air13.ai_vsn_id
WHERE
    ((air13.ai_air_date >= now() - INTERVAL '2 days') AND (air13.ai_air_date <= (now() + INTERVAL '7 days'))))
TO 'pdescrtest.json';
```

Here is a sample of the results where it is breaking on line 3 due to the double \s.

```
{"var pdescr = " : [
    {"ai_vsn_id" : 395617, "pde_text" : "and plant in the garden. It's the perfect present for America.        ", "pde_disp_ord" : 6},
    {"ai_vsn_id" : 328966, "pde_text" : "Artist Georgia O'Keeffe has been called the \\"Mother of American       ", "pde_disp_ord" : 1},
    {"ai_vsn_id" : 328966, "pde_text" : "Modernism,\\" well-known for her flowing, colorful works depicting      ", "pde_disp_ord" : 2},
    {"ai_vsn_id" : 328966, "pde_text" : "flowers and plants, dramatic cityscapes and Southwestern landscapes.  ", "pde_disp_ord" : 3},
    {"ai_vsn_id" : 328966, "pde_text" : "The half-hour documentary GEORGIA O'KEEFFE: A WOMAN ON PAPER          ", "pde_disp_ord" : 4},
]}
```

Any guidance anyone can give would be appreciated.